# doc.sty: Print codelinenumbers in index in tt font?

Tags: indexing, documentation, documentclass-writing

Is it possible to print the index numbers which are referring to a code line number instead of a page in typewirter font.

I know that I can change `\main`, but on this way I can’t change the format of the auto indexed commands.

**Example**

```
% \iffalse
%<*driver>
\ProvidesFile{example.dtx}
%</driver>
%<class>\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2009/01/01]
%<class>\ProvidesClass{example}
%
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{hypdoc}

\renewcommand{\main}[1]{\underline{\texttt{#1}}}

\CodelineIndex
\EnableCrossrefs

\begin{document}
  \DocInput{example.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%
% \DoNotIndex{\newcommand}
%
% \section{Usage}
% \DescribeMacro{\test} This is a stupid example
% for \cmd{\test}, but it prducec the right index
% formatting.
%
% \StopEventually{\PrintIndex}
%
% \section{Implementaion}
% \begin{macro}{\test}
% This is how Test is defined
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newcommand{\test}{Some text}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
% \begin{macro}{\supertest}
% And here \cmd{\test} is used in another macro
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newcommand{\supertest}{\test{} without sense}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
% \Finale
\endinput
```

build with

```
pdflatex example.dtx
makeindex -s gind.ist -o example.ind example.idx
pdflatex example.dtx
```

**Result**

[image: result]

But it should be
`\test` . . . . . . *1*,`1`,`2`
(with `1` underlined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\theCodelineNo}{%
  \reset@font\ttfamily\scriptsize\arabic{CodelineNo}}
\makeatother
```

after loading the class.

Indeed, in the index writing process, the class uses directly `\number\c@CodelineNo`, so this should work.

Writing also

```
\def\hdclindex#1#2#3{%
  \csname\ifx\\#2\\relax\else#2\fi\endcsname{%
    \hyperlink{HD.#1}{\texttt{#3}}%
    \HD@savedest@add{#1}%
  }%
}
```

will use typewriter type for the line numbers in the index, but consecutive line numbers will not be printed correctly (they form a unique link, so also the comma will be printed in typewriter type). This can be cured by calling `makeindex` with the `-r` option (that disables page ranges formation).

Comment: I tried it, but the font change affects only the line numbering in the implementation part but not the numbers in the index.

Comment: This seems to be quite difficult to solve. :(

Comment: My idea was to find the lines in `doc.sty` that generate the entry and change them to add `|texttt` but I failed to find these lines …

Comment: Unfortunately **doc** and **hypdoc** don't use the standard `\index` command, but do their own writing.

Comment: And can we (or better: you …) hack/patch into it? Could you please point me the relevant lines, so I can have a look myself.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delayd answer. I tried again and now it works. But I had to add `\renewcommand{\usage}[1]{{\let\texttt\relax\textit{#1}}}` to make your hack not affect the page numbers of `\DescribeMacro`. Thanks again!